# How do I initialize or show a nested form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I follow the complex nested forms in railscast and I made it work, a few tweaks here and there. But question is, how do I automatically load a nested form without using the controller?

```
def new
  @model = Model.new
  @model.child.build
end
```

many thanks!

Comment: please explain a bit more what do you need, you can do `@model = Model.new` and `@model.child.build` in views directly as well.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I automatically load a nested form without using the
>   controller?

The simple (incorrect) answer is to include a Partial which will define the ActiveRecord objects as above, like this:

```
#app/views/controllers/_your_partial.html.erb
<% model = Model.new %>
<% mode.child.build %>

<%= form_for model do |f| %>
...
```

The **problem** with this is that it goes against the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which is the equivalent of God in the Rails world

--

**MVC**

Your question is rather peculiar, as it goes against one of the core elements of Rails:

[image]

This means every *request* you make to your Rails application (through the URL) will have to be catered for by a `controller action`. The role of the controller is to configure / collect the `data` required to run the app, and then populate the view for the user.

When you want to "call the form without a controller", you're basically saying you want to go against these conventions. Unless you create a `gem` (which will allow you to extrapolate the ActiveRecord definition code outside of your controller), you'll have to use the controller.

There *is* a trick though...

--

**Class Method**

You'll be able to take the functionality you're using in your controller & create a [`class method`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) to handle it:

```
#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.build
        model = self.new
        model.child.build
        model
    end
end
```

This will allow you to call the following from your controller / partial:

```
@model = Model.build #-> instead of Model.new :)
```

Comment: I do use this, but I saw a sample in the interwebs but I can't get it to work (I am new to ruby and RoR).

Comment: Can you post your code? Class methods are standard practice - if you give me your code, I'll be able to look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def setup_person(person)
    returning(person) do |p|
      p.children.build if p.children.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

I found this on Ryan Daigle's site but I realize this is a bit outdated. I tried this but I get a returning is not defined or not a method.